# What host cores did Dolores take with her?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

At the end of Westworld's second season, Dolores has escaped in Charlotte's body to Arnold's mansion. From the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Passenger_(Westworld)):

> Dolores-Charlotte joins the evacuation team, taking several host cores with her.

We see 4 cores in her bag. Who do they belong to?

Comment: Something tells me that some of those cores are human.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has yet to be determined or presented to the audience.

> **ENTERTAINMENT WEEKLY:**  Do you know who each of those balls represent  in Dolores’ purse? Or is your cast on edge about which
>   characters Dolores found worthy of survival?
>
> **JONATHAN NOLAN:** We’ve had some interesting conversations. It’s a  large ensemble cast and sadly we’re saying goodbye to some people at
>   the end of this season. But as always with this show, who remains and
>   who doesn’t is something we’re having a lot of fun with. There’s going
>   to be a bit of a wait for a third season but we want to surprise and
>   hopefully delight people with the way things progress.
>
> **EW:** When we see Dolores walking with Charlotte out of the room at the end on the mainland, does that mean there are now two Doloreses
>   played by different actors?
>
> **JN:** Ehhh, not really. The question of who’s who and what we’re looking at is something we’re excited to play with. We’re excited to
>   withhold a little from the audience but … it’s complicated.
>   http://ew.com/tv/2018/06/24/westworld-season-2-finale-interview/

---

However, if one watches the final pre-credit scene, some notice that they way Tessa Thompson's character carries herself, especially her weapon, is rather reminiscent to Angela, but this is pure speculation at this point